# Linux Tool/Command for posting to a Message Queue?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

[This site](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html) gives a brief tutorial of Message Queues in Linux. I quote:

> For the sake of completeness, I'll include a brace of programs that
>   will communicate using message queues. The first, kirk.c adds messages
>   to the message queue, and spock.c retrieves them.

In the example "the sender" and "the receiver" are created via compiled binaries.

Is it possible to construct the sender in a shell script that uses some **existing** Linux commands/tools to send the message? And not have to create a binary (kirk in this case) to send the messages?

I was imagining something like this:

```
some-linux-command key "Hello World"
```

I realize I could simply create my own binary to do this - passing in the necessary parameters. However, I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I do not have to.